# Find a query that computes the time between first and second order of an ecommerce dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to compute the time between a first and second order in my ecommerce table (orders) for every customer. [image]

I found this document that is useful to select all the top n rows per group, but I am not sure how to pair it up with the computation of second order time - first order time  https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
SELECT customer_id, datediff(day, min(order_time), max(order_time)) 
     as avg_time
FROM ORDERS AS so
WHERE 
(select count(*) from ORDERS as se
   where se.customer_ID = so.customer_ID and se.order_time <= so.order_time
) <= 2
group by customer_id
having count(distinct order_time)>1
order by avg_time desc) t
```

However, it is wrong because it compute the max at the beginning from the whole dataset, which would be the latest order and not the second order.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can yoe please add the table as text or dbfiddle example

Comment: @ICasucci, use windows function (Lag) to order the data chronologically then you will have Transaction_ID and another column next_Transaction_Id

Comment: What database are you really using?  You tagged MySQL but the code looks like SQL Server.

Comment: sorry yes is it SQL server @GordonLinoff

Comment: @zip  how can I take in account the return orders in this expression? sometimes I have customers that made one order and one return, and I do not want to count them as two time purchaser.

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can I take in account the return orders in this expression? sometimes I have customers that made one order and one return, and I do not want to count them as two time purchaser.

Comment: If you are the designer of the database model, you can add a return table containing the transaction ID of the purchase being returned, date of return and other useful fields. And for the query you want you take all transaction ID except those that are in the return table.

Comment: @zip there are some cases where a customer returns an item and buys a new one though, and the transaction ID would be the same. Not sure if this workaround woudl fix it

Comment: In that case, in your original table you can have a status for the transactions. One transaction ID can be cancelled/returned. And when its cancelled/returned, you exclude the transaction ID with that cancelled/returned status. That will help you avoid duplicates

Comment: the return orders have  a negative SKU value, if that helps. How can I leverage that?

Comment: SELECT "Customer ID"
       ,"Transaction ID"
       ,"SKU"
       ,"Date"
       ,LAG("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "Customer ID" ORDER BY "Date") AS LastOrderDate
       ,DATEDIFF(dd, LAG("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "Customer ID" ORDER BY "Date"), "Date") AS DaysBetweenOrders
FROM ORDERS where sku >0 
;   @zip would this fix it?

Comment: This looks like @Mike R answer. IF thats the case and you have the status field for cancelled/returned orders, I would replace "from Orders" with "from (select * from Orders where status !='Cancelled')". Then it would exclude the returned Orders

Comment: @zip yes it is his answer I just added the where condition to exclude the 'negative SKUs' aka the returned items so I guess this way those rows would be not taken in account into the computation

Comment: Indeed, that should do it indeed. I havent run the tests. Let us know when you do lcasucci.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @zip I tested that and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, LAG/LEAD functions will give you what you need here. I assume you want this on a per customer basis.

```
 SELECT "Customer ID"
       ,"Transaction ID"
       ,"SKU"
       ,"Date"
       ,LAG("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "Customer ID" ORDER BY "Date") AS LastOrderDate
       ,DATEDIFF(dd, LAG("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY "Customer ID" ORDER BY "Date"), "Date") AS DaysBetweenOrders
FROM ORDERS
;
```

Comment: how can I take in account the return orders in this expression? sometimes I have customers that made one order and one return, and I do not want to count them as two time purchaser.

Answer (score 1):

So, given the following in postgres (which I have readily available):

```
so1=# SELECT * FROM table1;
 cust | tx  | sku |        _date        
------+-----+-----+---------------------
    1 | 111 |   3 | 2010-01-01 12:30:00
    2 | 222 |   1 | 2010-01-01 11:00:00
    2 | 222 |   2 | 2010-01-01 11:00:00
    3 | 333 |   7 | 2010-01-03 15:00:00
    1 | 444 |   8 | 2010-01-04 21:00:00
(5 rows)
```

The following allows to perform date arithmetic on consequetive rows (by date)

```
so1=# SELECT
so1-#     fst - snd
so1-# FROM (
so1(#     SELECT
so1(#         _date AS fst,
so1(#         lag(_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY _date) AS snd
so1(#     FROM
so1(#         table1) AS s;
    ?column?     
-----------------

 00:00:00
 01:30:00
 2 days 02:30:00
 1 day 06:00:00
(5 rows)
```

Comment: how can I take in account the return orders in this expression? sometimes I have customers that made one order and one return, and I do not want to count them as two time purchaser @wobr

Comment: You have a separate returns table (TPC style) or something else? Please provide more info on exactly what you wan in order to receive the correct respons.